# Create rubber animation on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm making my website and would like every letter in my title to have a rubber effect when you hover it. A clear example can be seen in the https://jacekjeznach.com/ home section.

I thought about making every letter a span with a class, which by hovering, changes its size and color. But I don't know how to create that "rubber" effect, or how to create an animation.

Any idea? I would appreciate it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an example but you need to have a little javascript for this to work well. This code uses jQuery which is already included in your Wordpress by default.

If you don't wish to use the javaScript, I've included the `:hover` CSS that you can uncomment and remove the javaScript but know that the animation will stop once the user is no longer hovering the element.

```js
$(".rubberBand").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationend", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("animated")  
})

$(".rubberBand").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("animated");        
})
```

```css
span.rubberBand {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

span.rubberBand.animated {
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand;
}

/*
WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT, UNCOMMENT THESE LINES AND YOU'LL SEE THAT THE ANIMATION STOPS WHEN YOU HOVER OUT
*/
/*
span.rubberBand:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand;
}
*/

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
  }

  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
  }

  65% {
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
  }

  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="rubberBand">H</span>
<span class="rubberBand">E</span>
<span class="rubberBand">L</span>
<span class="rubberBand">L</span>
<span class="rubberBand">O</span>
```

Comment: Thats awsome! Thanks for the great work. For some reason, if I copy this in Wordpress, the animation happens when the page loads, but not when I hover the letters. http://francodarget.com/

Comment: @FrancoDarget You're code is not wrapped inside a `<script></script>` element. If you look at the bottom of your page, below the footer, you'll see the code as text.

Comment: Also, if you found this code helpful, please upvote it or accept it as an answer so others may know that it's useful.